# Duplicate Primary Key with Composite Key, DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Quick Question, I'm new to NoSQL databases so excuse my lack of understanding on the subject but I am wondering, how do I use a combination of Primary and Composite keys in DynamoDB.  Take the Examples below.  Can I use the same primary key but with a different composite key to query the database?.  I want to order by data so I can query it either by date or District and I also want to persist a Map containing a Bills id and Name.  Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you are confusing primary key with hash key. Further reading: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelPrimaryKey

Comment: I am indeed confusing them but I think I'm more interested in the Hash and Range Type Primary Keys.  Lets say for example I save my objects using its id as the hash key and its date as its Range Type.  Imagine this scenario, how do I retrieve all the objects in the database that match a certain date?.  How do I do this kind of thing in a NoSql database.

Comment: Sorry I found some documentation that answers my question.  Thanks for the help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html#JavaDeclarativeTagsList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your comment question, you can't quickly query by range key.
You can only query on a hash key to get a list of dates.
Perhaps you should switch it and make the date hash, but then you can't query ranges.

When modeling DynamoDB you need to make sure you understand the limits and model accordingly.

EDIT to answer comment
You can have a table where hash is clientId and range is billId.
This will help you query all the bills for a client. If you want to filter them by type in the database you can add a [local secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) on the 'type' attribute and filter it fast (remember that we are still talking about secondary query. The first one was the clientId).

Also keep in mind that you can only use one index at a time (range-key is considered an index)

Comment: Would I miss the performance advantages of a database like dynamo if I query regularly by range?.  I want to first display a list of Bill names to the user on the UI first, after the user selects the Bill they want to use then I will retrieve that particular bill from DynamoDB.  What happens if I want to filter them on type?, do I have to create more entries with different hash key and range combos?, e.g. hashKey: id=1233 range: type;paid

Comment: no, the advantage is guaranteed if the data is spread evenly across the hash keys. I will edit my answer to add a schema for the other question

Comment: One more question.  I assume when you create a table you have to assign it a hashkey and a range, You cannot mix hashkeys with different ranges on the same table. e.g hash=clientId and range=billId or hash=clientId and range=paid?.  I assume this is the reason for secondary indexes.

Comment: well this is up to you. If the range key is S (string) - you can save multiple things on it. For instance XXX#billId and YYY#paid . If there will never be the same string for pair objects and billId objects they can also be mixed without XXX/YYY however, I think it's a bad pattern and will result in more bad than good

Comment: What about Multiple tables?, its considered a best practice by AWS, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html#GuidelinesForItems.MultipleTables.  Starting to wonder if a NoSQL database is a good fit, im using it because it scales well, that would be the main reason why.

Comment: multiple tables is actually what I'm doing in my company. We have no LSI yet and I like it. We started with only DynamoDB and added MySQL (RDS) when we needed it ...

Comment: How easy is it to manage your tables in DynamoDB?.  Lets say I want to add an index further down the line.  At the moment I can't see a way without recreating the tables, this isn't exactly feasible when its customer facing.  I would need to know every possible query I would ever use against my data before using the database live.  Thats not exactly how the real world works.  How easy is it to extend the Schema so to speak?.  Starting to think MongoDB would be a better choice.

Comment: you've put into words what I was trying to say. We don't use LSI because we prefer the flexibility of adding tables-as-index instead